# How to Read percentage value with sign(%) from Excel file using ClosedXml

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, closedxml

Input: Cell Value=6.25%;

```
var Value= ws1.Cell(rowNum, collNum).Value.ToString();
```

Output: 0.0625
Expected Output: 6.25%

Comment: Shouldn't your output be 0.0625?

Comment: Try .GetFormattedString() instead of .Value

Comment: Oh Sorry outpot is 0.0625 but i my Expected output Should be 6.25% .....

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. now its Working

Comment: @AlexK. Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution by using .GetFormattedString() insted of .Value